# how to get text of label that belongs to checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor

I'm trying to get the text of the labels that belong to checked radio buttons, but I can't and my code doesn't work correctly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var IS_SEX_Title
  $('input[name="IS_SEX"]:radio:checked').each(function() {
    IS_SEX_Title = $(this).parent().find('label').text();
  });
  alert(IS_SEX_Title)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <input  value="0" class="form-control psd-input-radio" name="IS_SEX"  id="IS_SEX_0" data-top-id="IS_SEX" checked="" type="radio">
  male
</label>
```

Comment: The parent *is* the `label` - remove `find()`. Also note that the `each()` is redundant as you can only have one checked radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('input[name="IS_SEX"]').parent('label').text();
```

It will return `male`

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o630z8j9/)

Answer (score 0):

The parent *is* the `label` - remove `find()`. Also note that the `each()` is redundant as you can only have one checked radio button per named group.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var IS_SEX_Title = $('input[name="IS_SEX"]:radio:checked').parent().text().trim();
  console.log(IS_SEX_Title)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <input  value="0" class="form-control psd-input-radio" name="IS_SEX"  id="IS_SEX_0" data-top-id="IS_SEX" checked="true" type="radio">
  male
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <input  value="0" class="form-control psd-input-radio" name="IS_SEX"  id="IS_SEX_1" data-top-id="IS_SEX" type="radio">
  female
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this **`$(this).parent().text();`** instead of **`$(this).parent().find('label').text();`** because label has text. so you don't need to find label.

See working snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var IS_SEX_Title
  $('input[name="IS_SEX"]:radio:checked').each(function() {
    IS_SEX_Title = $(this).parent().text();
  });
  alert(IS_SEX_Title);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline" style="margin-right:10px;">
           <input  value="0" class="form-control psd-input-radio" name="IS_SEX"  id="IS_SEX_0" data-top-id="IS_SEX" checked="" type="radio">male</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are changing the value inside forEach. Try put the alert inside the foreach then you can access directly by class. Take a look bellow:

```js
var IS_SEX_Title
$('input[name="IS_SEX"]:radio:checked').each(function() {
  IS_SEX_Title = $('.radio-inline').text();
  console.log(IS_SEX_Title);
  alert(IS_SEX_Title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <input  value="0" class="form-control psd-input-radio" name="IS_SEX"  id="IS_SEX_0" data-top-id="IS_SEX" checked="" type="radio">
  male
</label>
```